# Unable to connect aioodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, python-asyncio, pyodbc

I want to connect to MS SQL db via aioodbc.

Here is the code, which follows the given example:

```
import asyncio
import aioodbc

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
async def connect_db():
    dsn = 'Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=123.456.789.55,1000/mycompany;\
           Database=Asia_client;User=myname;\
           Password=mypass'
    conn = await aioodbc.connect(dsn=dsn, loop=loop)

    cur = await conn.cursor()
    await cur.execute("SELECT top 100 *;")
    rows = await cur.fetchall()
    await cur.close()
    await conn.close()

loop.run_until_complete(connect_db())
```

However, I got the following error:

```
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].  (87) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Are there anythings wrong with the driver, server or login format?

Comment: maybe something is wrong with your `Server` value, it doesn't seem like valid URI

Comment: In sqlalchemy, the following connection is successful:

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://myname:mypass@123.456.789.55,1000/mycompany?driver=ODBC+Driver+11+for+SQL+Server")

Comment: also you can try changing driver to `Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}` (with braces). If it does not help, then it is likely `pyodbc` bug, and in that case I advise to copy your question to https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues

Comment: @John: were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: yes, I made it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use port number **and** instance name with ODBC driver. You must provide port **or** instance name